# Prevent GridSpec subplot seperation changing with figure size

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I am wanting to create a grid of plots with no intermediate space.

Which would look something like this:

[image]

Code 1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure()

gs = GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])

fig.show()
```

However when I add data the spacing between the sub-plots is dependent on dimensions of the figure. (Which can be seen by changing the dimensions of the window opened by fig.show().)

As an example:

[image]

Code 2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

gs = GridSpec(2, 2, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])

for axis in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]:
    axis.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))

fig.show()
```

So, preferably still using GridSpec, is it possible to force the plots to remain together?
The only other alternative I can think of is to access the size of the plots and use these dimensions in `plt.figure(figsize=(##,##))`, but I can't seem to access the numbers.

Note: The number of plots will vary as well as hight/width ratios. (e.g. `GridSpec(2, 3,  width_ratios=[10,10,1], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)` where I would use the last column to hold the colour bar that is used for all the plots.)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
*Python 2.7.10, Matplotlib 1.4.3*
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found two quick and dirty methods:

## Method 1: Using `figsize`

Setting the `figsize` keyword argument in `plt.figure` with a width and height that matches the same aspect ratio as the data works reasonably well this little effort.

[Result from Method 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GtCJ.png)

Method 1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

import numpy as np

length_x_axis = 30
length_y_axis = 10

rows  = 3
columns = 2

fig_height = 5.

height = length_y_axis * rows
width = length_x_axis  * columns

plot_aspect_ratio= float(width)/float(height)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_height  * plot_aspect_ratio, fig_height ))

gs = GridSpec(rows, columns, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 0])
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 1])

for axis in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    axis.imshow(np.random.random((length_y_axis , length_x_axis )))

fig.savefig("testing.png")
```

## Method 2: Using `set_anchor`

Using the set_anchor method for each axis gives a better result but it requires a bit more effort and from some quick tests it won't work for plot arrays greater than 3x2.

[Result from Method 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k78LY.png)

Method 2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2, 3, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax1.set_anchor("SE")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax2.set_anchor("S")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 2])
ax3.set_anchor("SW")

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax4.set_anchor("NE")

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax5.set_anchor("N")

ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 2])
ax6.set_anchor("NW")

for axis in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    axis.imshow(np.random.random((10 , 10 )))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, `gridspec` does not override the default `figsize` that you set up like this: `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,8)`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `imshow` uses `aspect=equal`, so your plots become square. Try using `aspect=auto` to prevent that.

Comment: This does work. Unless the images are meant to be square. If the x and y axis are the same length, I would expect the original axes to be square to begin with but that is obviously not the case.

Comment: @Haydon Looking at your first figure, I assumed you don't want them to be square. But your code is symmetrical, so I wonder why the figure isn't. Does matplotlib add more vertical spacing by default?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a [Nested GridSpec using SubplotSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#a-complex-nested-gridspec-using-subplotspec):

The, above linked, matplotlib example code produces this:

[image]

Code, from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/plotting/examples/demo_gridspec06.py):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

try:
    from itertools import product
except ImportError:
    # product is new in v 2.6
    def product(*args, **kwds):
        pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
        result = [[]]
        for pool in pools:
            result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
        for prod in result:
            yield tuple(prod)


def squiggle_xy(a, b, c, d, i=np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.05)):
    return np.sin(i*a)*np.cos(i*b), np.sin(i*c)*np.cos(i*d)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

# gridspec inside gridspec
outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

for i in range(16):
    inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3,
            subplot_spec=outer_grid[i], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
    a, b = int(i/4)+1,i%4+1
    for j, (c, d) in enumerate(product(range(1, 4), repeat=2)):
        ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid[j])
        ax.plot(*squiggle_xy(a, b, c, d))
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        fig.add_subplot(ax)

all_axes = fig.get_axes()

#show only the outside spines
for ax in all_axes:
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)
    if ax.is_first_row():
        ax.spines['top'].set_visible(True)
    if ax.is_last_row():
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
    if ax.is_first_col():
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(True)
    if ax.is_last_col():
        ax.spines['right'].set_visible(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is something that I investigated but imshow is a bit strange: what seems to be created is a fixed size image and that seems to cause problems.

Comment: Exactly, `imshow` is causing trouble here. Check the answer of @AndreyPortnoy

Answer (score 1):

## Use: width_ratios=[2,1]

For example,

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0,width_ratios=[2,1])

# first 
ax = fig.add_subplot(outer_grid[0])
ax.plot(gan.arr_g_loss,label='Generator Loss')
ax.plot(gan.arr_d_loss_real,label='Discriminator Loss on Real data')
ax.plot(gan.arr_d_loss_fake,label='Discriminator Loss on Fake data')
ax.set_title('Loss')
ax.legend()
fig.add_subplot(ax,figsize=(15, 6))

    
# second
inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(5, 5,subplot_spec=outer_grid[1], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
images = gan.generate_images().cpu().numpy()[:,0,:,:]
for j, i in enumerate(images):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(inner_grid[j])
    ax.imshow(i,cmap='gray')
#     ax.plot(x)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.autoscale(False)
    
    fig.add_subplot(ax)
```

[image]